# Rails Has One Rspec Test tells me Unitialized Constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, constants, shoulda

I have a have one relationship between two models. The relationship works, the problem however is that when I write a Rspec test with shoulda matchers I get returned an error.

```
 Failure/Error: it { should have_one(:userresetpassword)}
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant User::Userresetpassword
```

My code in the `user.rb`

```
has_one :userresetpassword
```

My rspec test

```
describe "associations" do
  it { should have_one(:userresetpassword)}
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your association is mis-named, and either rails, shoulda-matchers or both are having a hard time guessing the class name from it.

You have two choices. First, and preferable is to rename the association to be conventional:

`has_one :user_reset_password`

This will allow rails to correctly guess the classname `UserResetPassword`

Second, you could simply remove the guesswork and tell rails what the classname is. This is only preferable if you can't or very much do not want to change the association name.

`has_one :userresetpassword, :class_name => "UserResetPassword"`

Comment: `require 'spec_helper'` is in the spec file. I just omitted it for brevity.

Comment: It looks then that shoulda or rails aren't sure what your intended class name is, what is the name of the association's class? Your association name would indicate that it is `Userresetpassword`.

Comment: Close, it's `UserResetPassword`.

Comment: Ah, did not know Rails could do that. Thanks.